# NodeJS: Como fazer um 'system("pause")' ou um 'ReadKey()'?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou executando um código JS utilizando o Sublime Text, o cmd fecha automaticamente após a execução do código JS, logo não vejo os resultados então pensei em usar algo semelhante a função system("pause") ou a função getch() do C/C++ também existe a ReadKey() do C#.

Uns exemplos básicos de que procuro no JavaScript em outras linguagens:

C#

```
using System;

class Exe{
    static void Main(){
        // Apesar de Não estar no Padrão .NET o Código funciona Perfeitamente  
        Console.Write("Olá Mundo!\nPressione Qualquer tecla para Encerrar a Execução do Programa...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Python 3

```
print('Olá Mundo!\nPressione Enter para Encerrar a Execução do Programa...', end='')
sysPause = str(input(''))       # Precisa pressionar Enter, diferente dos Outros exemplos...
```

C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    printf("Olá Mundo!\n");
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout << "Olá Mundo!\nPressione Qualquer tecla para Encerrar a Execução do Programa...";
    getch();        // ou getche()

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

bom não sei se interpretei sua pergunta da forma correta mas vou tentar te ajudar.

No Javascript puro não se pensava em receber input pelo terminal (*alias nem se pensava em executar o javascript pelo terminal*);

Por isso você não encontra um método nativo como em outras linguagens, durante a evolução do javascript foi criado alguns módulos que trabalham coisas como o fluxo de **input**.

---

Talvez o mais notável deles seja o **readline**, que faz parte do próprio conjuto de módulos internos do node hoje em dia.

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question('Qual sua idade? ', (answer) => {
  console.log(`Sua idade é ${answer}`);
  rl.close();
});
```

Observe o exemplo acima, fragmento retirado e adaptado da documentação do [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html)

---

Caso esteja usando o **npm** ou algum outro gerenciador de dependências, você pode optar por opções mais simples como:

**[readline-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/readline-sync)** ( isso mesmo de síncrono )

```
const readline = require('readline-sync');

// resto do seu codigo.

readline.question('\npress any key!');
```

eu particularmente gosto bastante, por ser mais simples que o **readline** e não precisar encadear 'promises'.

---

Bom lembrando que existem outros modulos que trabalham em cima do input 'readline', uma pesquisa no npmjs com a keyword readline revela umas bibliotecas interessantes.

[Resultados da Pesquisa](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords:readline)

---

Basicamente é isso, só fiquei com uma dúvida você diz estar executando pelo sublime... não conheço muito a ferramenta.. mas dependendo como você executa o processo é invocado por segundo plano (assim não tem como você dar input)... de qualquer forma faça um teste no terminal / CMD se ficar em dúvidas...

espero ter ajudado, abraços.

Comment: ajudou mesmo cara valeu, no caso do sublime criei 2 build para o JS, um que apenas executa o comando "node", "$file_name" e executa o código JS no console do sublime (que não funciona para ler dados do teclado, mesmo no python, java porém exibe todos os prints definidos, então vejo os resultados, o que tu disse, não aceita os input do usuário), e o "start", "node", "$file_name" que executa o script no cmd do Windows, porém após execução do código o cmd é automaticamente fechado pelo SO.

Comment: mais uma vez obrigado